# how to open a xml as a html with python requests

Tags: python, html, xml

hey guys can you help me please? i want to open a xml with python requests.and i want to open some certain rows in a html site. the name of my xml is out.xml
this is my actual code:

```
import lxml.html.builder as html
from lxml import etree

nodeTable=html.BODY(html.TABLE)
for i in range(0, 20 ):
    nodeRow=html.TR(html.TD("user", style="background-color:#FF0000"), html.TD("blabla"), html.TD("zweite zeile"))
    nodeTable.append(nodeRow)


print etree.tostring(nodeTable)
with open("out.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(nodeTable))
```

obviusly i dont want to have "first row" and "second row". in this position i want to have me xml-results. i appreciate your help :)

Comment: What does `requests` have to do with parsing XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after succesly import this file you could use Css grids ( Display :grids) and play whit ur row situation in your html file